# Python Excel Spreadsheet Reading

Tags: python, excel

```
import pandas as pd
    
#Read File
contacts_file = pd.read_excel("Contacts_Sheet.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", email=[1])
    
#Get emails
real_email = contacts_file["@" in contacts_file["Company Email:"]]
    
#Output Doc
real_email.to_excel("All_emails.xlsx")
```

I have a spreadsheet with emails and company names, but there is a lot of companies where emails could not be found and in place is "NA". I want to create a program that will take out all the emails in column 2 with the company names in column 1, but I cannot figure out how to "search" for the emails. My thought was the find the "@" within each string because that is the only thing that differentiates the emails from other strings. That is what I attempted to do in the code above.

Comment: For what I remember of `pandas` you can read out the column titles, get the index of whatever columns you want and use them to read the data in lines, line per line. That of course if the table has a header. Otherwise you could read line per line and use some `re.regex` to find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need `str.contains`

i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company' : ['A','B'],
             'Email'  : ['test@test.com',np.nan]})

print(df)

  Company          Email
0       A  test@test.com
1       B            NaN

df_new = df[df['Email'].str.contains('@')==True]

print(df_new)

      Company          Email
    0       A  test@test.com
```